# Verify JS Method Exists Before Calling

Tags: javascript

I am referencing a third party library in a SCRIPT tag and it's getting blocked by Ad Blockers. This results in errors because the library isn't loaded and JS is trying to use methods that now do not exist. What's the best way test if a method exists before calling it?

EXAMPLE

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://path-to-api"></script>
```

In the console, the JS API is blocked as such:
gpt.js:1 GET https://path-to-api net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: install it in your app instead of using a cdn?

Comment: @Craicerjack - I wish we could but that would mean maintaining a third party code that is changing all the time.

Comment: it wouldnt though. Its how stuff is regularly done in apps. You download the current version and use that, no breaking changes no upgrades until you come along and do it.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if a function exists by doing the following:

```
if (yourLib && typeof yourLib.method === "function") { 
 // it exists / is not undefined
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And if it's a function, would something like this:


if (typeof functionName === "function"){ 
   // do stuff
}